# How to stop turtle(python) from giving me this error: 'int' object has no attribute 'undobuffer'?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How can i stop turtle from returning this error?
'int' object has no attribute 'undobuffer'

```
import turtle
import time
import math

t=turtle.Turtle

def petalo():
    t.circle(250,50)
    t.circle(250,-50)
petalo()

´´´
```

Comment: `t=turtle.Turtle` does not actually create a turtle; it just creates an alias for the `Turtle` class.  You want `t=turtle.Turtle()`.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73854949/edit) the question to include the full error + traceback.

Answer (score 0):

t=turtle.Turtle does not instantiate an instance of object `Turtle`. As per @jasonharper's comment above, you need to add the parenthesis after and things will work.

```
t = turtle.Turtle()

t.circle(250,50)

...
```